# Delaying Loaders

Tags: android

Is it always necessary to initLoader from onCreate in a Fragment?  What if critical arguments for the loader are dependent on the results of another loader?

i.e.  You have 2 loaders: LoaderA, and LoaderB.  LoaderB needs the result from LoaderA to run.  Both LoaderA and LoaderB are initialized in onCreate of a fragment, but LoaderB is given no arguments so that it intentionally fails.
Once LoaderA finishes, LoaderB is restarted with new arguments so that it can perform its desired request.

Loader initialization in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_A, new Bundle(), this);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_B, null, mLoaderBCallback);
}
```

Call backs for LOADER_A in fragment:

```
@Override
public Loader<MyResultObject> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) { 
    return new LoaderA(getActivity(), args);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<MyResultObject> loader, final MyResultObject result) {
    if (result != null) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", result.getId());

        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_B, args, mLoaderBCallback);
    }
}
```

Definition of mLoaderBCallback in fragment:

```
private LoaderBCallback mLoaderBCallback = new LoaderBCallback();
```

(The implementation of LoaderBCallback is not important, its just the standard LoaderCallbacks interface that creates an instance of LoaderB and handles when the loader is finished.)

LoaderB class (please excuse any potential compiler errors with this class definition, its just an example):

```
public class LoaderB<List<AnotherResultObject>> extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<AnotherResultObject>> { 
    private Bundle mArgs;

    public LoaderB(Context context, Bundle args) {
        super(context);
        mArgs = args;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AnotherResultObject> loadInBackground() {
        if (mArgs == null) {
            // bail out, no arguments.
            return null;
        }


        // do network request with mArgs here
        return MyStaticClass.performAwesomeNetworkRequest(mArgs);
    }

    // boiler plate AsyncTaskLoader stuff here
    ...... 

}
```

Is there a better way?  Can we do without the initLoader for LoaderB?

Edit: I am under the impression that loaders ALWAYS have to be initialized in onCreate, so that they can handle configuration changes.  This may be true ONLY for loaders in Activities .  Do loaders created in Fragments get managed no matter where they are initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can init a loader anywhere in your code.

In your case you should replace your `restartLoader` in onLoadFinished with `initLoader`. Just remove the initLoader from your onActivityCreated for LOADER_B

Also, you should check the ID of the loader in onLoadFinished so you know which loader finished.

edit: you are using a separate listener for the `LOADER_B` callback so my ID checking point kinda gets defeated there.. but at any rate.. you can combine them into one if you want

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<MyResultObject> loader, final MyResultObject result) {
    switch (loader.getId())
    {
      case LOADER_A:
         if (result != null) {
             Bundle args = new Bundle();
             args.putInt("id", result.getId());
             // i put "this" as the callback listener. you can use your custom one here if you want
             getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_B, args, this);
         }
         break;
      case LOADER_B:
         //do whatever
         break;
}
```

Comment: Any idea if the loader will still survive lifecycle events (such as orientation change) if you dont init them somewhere important?

Comment: It should. The loader result gets persisted through the orientation change.